# Using Regular Expression and Jquery to Manipulate Date Field

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm hoping someone can help me with the targeting the date from a post

from this   "Wed, 27 Feb 2013 09:00:00 +1100"

to this

```
         <span class="day">27</span>
         <span class="month">Feb</span>
```

Ignoring the year and time. The idea is that I can then style the day and month so it sits to the left of the title.

Class day and month can then sit inside a parent div with a darkish background like so [1 http://www.canberra.edu.au/media/test/date.jpg](http://www.canberra.edu.au/media/test/date.jpg)

I'm guessing something like this?

```
 $("h6").html(function(index, old) {
   return old.replace(some regular expression/, '<span class="day">$1</span><span class="month>$2</span>"');
 });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea how to write any Regular Expression :( I will however endeavor to try in the near future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var matches = /^.{3}, (\d+) (.{3}) \d+/.exec("Wed, 27 Feb 2013 09:00:00 +1100")

// matches[1] --> "27"
// matches[2] --> "Feb"
```

Comment: Thanks Makssym, the .exec("some random date that changes")? Is that right? The date I showed is an example of one date. there's going to be many posts with date fields

Comment: yes it should work for any date formatted in similar way: three letters for day of the week and three letters for the month

Comment: Would really appreciate it if you showed me how its constructed within a jQuery function so I can learn? regards. NickP